# Host.CreateDefaultBuilder not loading environment config overrides

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've reviewed the other questions on this topic, but none of them seem to have the same issue.  Configuration:

- Target Framework: netcoreapp3.1
- Console application (but NOT ASP.Net... just plain console app.)

According to the docs, this set of calls:

```
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        builder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
        var host = builder.Build();
```

Should automagically load the appropriate environment config overrides.

(ConfigureServices in this case just loads one dummy service)

I have an appconfig.json, an appconfig.Development.json, both marked as "Copy Always" and do show up in the target directory.

They have just one entry each, the same entry, but different values:

```
  {
    "Foo": "Bar" 
  }
```

and

```
  {
    "Foo": "Quz" 
  }
```

I have these environment variables set in the launchSettings.json:

```
  {
    "profiles": {
      "ConsoleApp1": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run the application it says it's in the correct enviornment:

```
        var hostEnv = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IHostEnvironment)) as IHostEnvironment;

        Console.WriteLine($"Environment: {hostEnv.EnvironmentName}");
```

Displays:

```
    Environment: Development
```

But when I try to retrieve the config value, I get the base value, not the override:

```
        var config = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration)) as IConfiguration;
        var children = config.GetChildren();
        var foo = children.First(c => c.Key == "Foo");
        Console.WriteLine($"Foo: {foo.Value}");
```

Displays:

```
    Foo: Bar
```

But based on the override, it should show "Foo: Quz".

Right after the build completes, looking at the host and digging down shows that it seems like it will try to load the Development file:
[image: DebugViewOfHostDevelopmentConfig]

But when retrieving the config root itself, it seems like it's empty:
[image: DebugViewOfEmptyDevelopmentConfig]

I checked the file in the bin folder and it is definitely not empty.

Comment: Set a breakpoint where the host is build, and check the configuration providers (they're pretty easy to navigate). Do you see any provider referencing `appsettings.Development.json`?

Comment: @Ray I added more information to answer your question.  Which honestly makes the problem even more confusing.

Comment: What's even weirder is that I recreated the solution with your source, but on .NET 6 (don't currently have .NET Core 3 installed), and it works perfectly... Can you try recreating those JSON files from scratch? Not like a BOM or some weird encoding error made it fail loading the `Development.json` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer here is both embarrassing and anti-climactic.  I am tempted to delete the question, but perhaps this will help someone else.

The answer is that the file name I used was not:

appsettings.Development.json

but

appsettings.Development..json

Note carefully that there are two periods before json, which is exceedingly hard to see in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Great to hear what the problem of this was, I was already wondering if it was a silly oversight :o)

Comment: In my case, the `appsettings.Development.json` name was fine, BUT, in the `.csproj` file, `CopyToOutputDirectory` was set as `Never` (set by default when the file was created). Being `Never`, the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` set in `launchSettings.json` wasn't working, obviously…